# Ejabberd: How to limit the fetching of jabber user directory (JUD)

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I'm developing a client jabberd application for mobile(android) using (a)Smack.

Since, in my application, the users are registered by their phone numbers, the application should be able to recognize which contact has a jabber account on the server and suggest him/her for chatting.

After googlling the web I found that there is a jabber user directory (JUD) which I can use to check there is an account for a specific mobile number or not. (I'm using UserSearchManager).

My questions:

1- It seems that there is no record in JUD for a user who has not updated his vCard yet, so I cannot find him. Is there any solution to check the existence of this kind of users?

2- It seems that by using JUD, everyone outside of my application can fetch some important information of users such as mobile numbers, emails, etc. Is there any solution to limit JUD search engine? (for example, getting only "user field" as a input and returning only "full name field" of existing accounts or other useful limitation).

So by this way, I can recognize which person from the contact list has an account on the server and also other people cannot fetch important information of the exiting users.

Any command or advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: No one knows the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think it is possible as default, without customizing ejabberd application code.